# django views not able to configure filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView,DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")


class HomePageView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

  model = Post
  template_name = 'home.html'
  context_object_name = 'deeppost'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['deeppost'] = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return context
```

Everytime I use `author=request.user`, I get an error saying the following:

```
NameError at /
name 'request' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'request' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Django\Django\MyProject\Pitsnews\views.py in get_context_data, line 24
Python Executable:  C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Django\\Django\\MyProject',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deepd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2018.3-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Fri, 23 Mar 2018 18:26:02 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\deepd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\list.py in get
        context = self.get_context_data() ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Django\Django\MyProject\Pitsnews\views.py in get_context_data
        context['deeppost'] = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: use `self.request.user` instead of `request.user`

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `request` directly without using the CBV - List View Instance. You need to access request object inside generic views as follows

```
self.request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use self.request

```
  class HomePageView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):


  model = Post
  template_name = 'home.html'
  context_object_name = 'deeppost'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['deeppost'] = Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
    return context
```

Comment: suppose we wanted to show only title and not body ,

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand

Comment: I am having trouble understanding a few things about django , In the html template when i write deeppost.title and deeppost.body , The Title and the body gets returned to html , When i try the same thing in django shell it does not , So i want to understand how the filters exactly work , for every app view do i have to create a different query set , ?. when i post.objects.all , should it not show every object in the data base ?.  like date published etc etc